# Controlling zlim values for contourplot

Tags: r, lattice

I am having a problem with 'lattice' graphics contour plots. I have been trying to create a contourplot using the code below, and am running into an issue with the display ranges. Basically, the contourpplot function uses the ranges for my response(z) variable, ABSerror (See below).

[ABSerror http://danielcoakley.com/project/Testing/Temperature.png](http://danielcoakley.com/project/Testing/Temperature.png)

However, the plotted data does not ever reach these 'min,max' limits as they are averaged by the predictor variables (hour, weekday). Is it possible to calculate the display range for lattice graphs and set these as the new limits for the colour legend? I don't want to set absolute limits for the z vector as this would make the code less robust, and would need to change every time I run it.

```
plot<-contourplot(ABStemp ~ hour * weekday,
                   aspect=0.3,
                   data = df,
                   cuts = 200,
                   #labels=TRUE,
                   contour=FALSE,
                   region = TRUE,
                   pretty=FALSE,
                   xlab = "Hour of Day",
                   ylab = "Day of Week",
                   col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("blue","yellow","red")),
                   zlim = range(100, finite = TRUE)
)
```

I've included 500 rows of my data frame below:

```
    df<-structure(list(ABStemp = c(2.33891051530419, 4.66977185341213, 
7.69092629549917, 11.1259634956075, 12.4989344259194, 10.4766508811911, 
12.1333252861115, 13.1427111020819, 13.8395728027101, 14.3513578101205, 
10.1150137331259, 5.14486679995218, 0.584418923890536, 2.36822622616402, 
1.90256632417697, 10.8309946541286, 14.0244639969632, 11.750660392261, 
10.9786334115844, 10.8389489143245, 9.88807810478433, 8.41323248299517, 
7.76005654828338, 2.23432319307088, 1.42651575885196, 3.97818093025987, 
5.98364201068521, 12.1327113715202, 16.6630927878909, 19.6025409795866, 
22.3533380207585, 21.6664228195007, 19.566910344456, 17.5305602166806, 
11.4138883749256, 4.47846199645294, 1.18418216015379, 4.95907843935502, 
4.15198230849739, 9.67593500154633, 14.0796157127847, 13.6682636683508, 
12.722836336779, 10.7137810035488, 9.31647396260888, 8.4024476064816, 
8.19525956966761, 3.37281771175294, 1.56437287656987, 5.40527765711733, 
13.5646511429841, 19.9655662099298, 23.6707556603167, 23.041197437406, 
21.3744768866254, 19.4214241150162, 19.1913001394706, 20.4763853858403, 
15.5308197426484, 9.40558035637685, 2.71528217047851, 3.08101029716437, 
3.37055247240881, 13.7953427517124, 18.6345920345412, 17.9883673749729, 
16.1619966461944, 14.4532078155512, 13.438212587822, 12.3720331692208, 
11.5153279333021, 1.81452101474621, 0.839654322007979, 4.1615787024834, 
11.6661758369217, 18.6811456671031, 23.2047102887316, 24.6750744255767, 
25.0222357414079, 25.7827288787888, 25.9782548940527, 24.6556924738125, 
20.5127706187546, 16.2556172057107, 12.5271296183477, 10.9611131864043, 
10.6150951792667, 22.3928563301905, 26.6681067231922, 24.6755909702781, 
23.2147294729545, 23.1323425131293, 23.3963336947643, 23.5573438900773, 
24.0301828927208, 8.49753243473921, 10.1805006078075, 12.2889694647281, 
15.7115236865939, 19.1085647003559, 21.1845732121901, 21.9782038074943, 
24.8715308127409, 24.0473711694237, 24.6904786262923, 22.5355252564063, 
20.4151021787812, 16.9746540335269, 9.24661888836837, 3.79265111395731, 
1.27631858358483, 12.402645060579, 17.2985901762333, 17.1313376423964, 
17.729811376458, 16.8225534613836, 15.1472900538297, 14.0517596861097, 
14.2376128219004, 0.308278216436768, 3.84192101024975, 13.188327199087, 
20.7074441529515, 27.3158262894137, 30.3349400179668, 31.3056271507191, 
32.5009019988318, 34.8630477283387, 33.374981820956, 30.2674519850418, 
24.9188176080028, 21.1840570064588, 17.9686717995784, 14.3467483048419, 
11.2691128813087, 23.8337490161465, 29.0849391270845, 29.6248186944942, 
29.386012054552, 28.7637847709596, 28.9110971378641, 28.8277975551496, 
28.8258095725158, 11.1482020511646, 10.3048686249461, 11.5537911454279, 
12.6487635415593, 15.141051096692, 18.4207035759421, 20.3921364957162, 
20.6986391864082, 22.3339225779584, 28.0766456499598, 30.2756390992694, 
28.4911213679877, 24.9888695614122, 20.4586080547411, 15.9841052888571, 
12.8901223486949, 24.4428240988806, 29.5586648421351, 28.3313230515127, 
27.0962382671756, 26.6790294807476, 26.3573300936104, 25.7992038364494, 
25.4855976543897, 7.35840040803988, 7.25201675398457, 9.725461523272, 
12.1342164312733, 13.1300616778934, 11.0174841271484, 10.4754255228911, 
9.50442956311057, 9.9402468322571, 10.5492444949961, 6.73672003535463, 
0.404446353941678, 2.68410551115763, 3.92625944672239, 3.83526016159428, 
2.99582288008988, 10.2444997945327, 16.1754244224394, 16.4315630892153, 
16.1257174992647, 15.3103781494378, 14.9008093717245, 14.6479919804145, 
15.0774193136139, 3.14483111523805, 4.40015938431536, 6.30335425421752, 
7.89295676809648, 10.3873658409837, 11.1675458065063, 11.2239362409328, 
13.4786551231579, 13.1174923553482, 11.8463935602633, 12.7792370089478, 
8.92853946342597, 3.67638327509499, 1.44336933818614, 3.7460763269343, 
2.80373132419384, 10.6758687377781, 17.1292041998935, 17.9235639821042, 
16.7225906653072, 15.5378208669432, 14.8132669217501, 14.965291900554, 
14.4626701869086, 2.09918561880569, 5.78385439843915, 10.7115515863618, 
18.3161496586981, 18.8453323554176, 20.1504317889165, 20.5243338520425, 
23.0946561914882, 23.1229411411489, 21.4766474646763, 18.8629064835698, 
13.6232806695288, 8.87195358826412, 3.02138370287754, 1.01567714013273, 
0.855184425602785, 15.2952996338701, 21.4434489591344, 20.5409630399889, 
19.0485834710192, 18.4566381805445, 17.4914927823451, 16.9949066569197, 
17.2394708863446, 5.20422190837278, 6.17270380733072, 5.42723981712398, 
4.91201796522349, 6.86605674843221, 8.9937132547134, 9.77633825599795, 
11.8107916732391, 16.043897776083, 17.3012176145297, 15.9028994432813, 
8.67297044050019, 5.16161707362852, 2.60348086326685, 1.20894961279237, 
2.51983065586451, 12.7011652003945, 17.0221447562056, 16.5190241116339, 
15.8870123508507, 15.4281483757257, 14.6144445210435, 13.2463831343735, 
12.6455956591155, 1.43836514820975, 7.3964941173677, 15.6589628080384, 
20.3821287445914, 24.6713477136591, 27.6904620792603, 28.5654304282508, 
25.3036289389789, 23.3449995578065, 23.0438525984448, 22.3306002371854, 
19.8544630570727, 14.9729598687669, 8.7587370696577, 5.31643600296484, 
4.04921813305131, 15.9829567620533, 21.3550401702375, 21.3824061491415, 
22.1984029205243, 22.4680353770285, 22.8554518167813, 23.0539756815934, 
23.5210387764831, 8.33814328095043, 9.55199051953161, 12.399383026239, 
14.4229377889505, 16.5763561723988, 16.059960214447, 17.6171246534286, 
21.3886648589456, 25.8181985070404, 24.5832331438196, 20.3333383167425, 
16.9244071165871, 15.8900358018522, 13.842652322184, 9.41731422210656, 
6.87007359112986, 17.2315876647855, 21.8982393005026, 22.1040991214791, 
21.8963615899734, 21.3128631580006, 21.1956782666886, 21.3259415120726, 
22.1871281639499, 7.38341716187449, 10.0050435819574, 15.5578500812052, 
17.6701921784541, 24.6080333615887, 29.3240271398202, 32.9230192385226, 
36.1174965373569, 38.200145076904, 36.6356882807734, 34.1940872924714, 
29.0602322683995, 23.4755814686931, 17.1688634312255, 10.5046421189841, 
6.42452005979931, 23.6418303116755, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 54.4343511257372, 
2.82289846623857, 6.36470006309094, 9.35271310858323, 14.9183391138978, 
19.7911161231157, 23.6336700416108, 25.7408728308815, 29.6525364862642, 
35.0274565367524, 38.5647202768138, 38.9995901261482, 35.1574124906668, 
28.7562081067795, 19.7627823633146, 12.8232222891012, 7.16499577741958, 
24.326308948197, 29.9224828411809, 29.3190199333518, 28.4295405828911, 
27.1628370657564, 26.1315997390072, 24.854988187972, 23.9801017080776, 
6.23517119408303, 8.3530231126271, 17.6653627336558, 25.9994213088618, 
36.2609324085035, 36.9365270157112, 29.3130105060826, 24.9156375902589, 
20.2354035394718, 17.9195087953262, 17.6894987728821, 11.6173525273901, 
5.79071235499063, 2.20374299938686, 0.09282185071742, 0.252230390627006, 
14.8073827079744, 19.256744346541, 17.4414878022219, 15.5101496678282, 
13.3277769079227, 11.2014545744602, 9.04785296211735, 7.70497585988905, 
2.70107195580814, 0.567589042929954, 4.41529902811057, 2.27774764209442, 
5.78721696829642, 10.6062617324736, 14.0445971430991, 18.0539144777537, 
21.5232028045893, 24.0158053088079, 25.8407179578528, 21.8342515181315, 
13.6919908435447, 4.0255627802668, 0.665949933004891, 0.208953214880797, 
16.1561669086234, 21.4497981663637, 383.067368925988, NA, NA, 
NA, 133.631551984593, 15.170591109258, 0.395827787471503, 0.269068190956889, 
3.50358059070192, 3.01677307944915, 2.00600287832979, 1.34682034030451, 
0.741245171651234, 1.19986776789557, 0.443705360449056, 0.212748459428304, 
1.06686877230414, 0.644617596270293, 0.80585339118931, 2.73257367450756, 
5.61775101084879, 6.46683498731927, 5.53032831060134, 8.85927149838813, 
6.79263511135433, 4.95326747917033, 3.49094953886742, 1.95123597400578, 
0.231727674223854, 1.13819878503669, 4.49692523622297, 3.3496788250999, 
0.60491692162872, 5.40141722711159, 6.73203968177679, 9.10727409649512, 
9.12357601422001, 9.85039555082153, 10.47895829976, 8.97590521908966, 
6.24612668446798, 2.87472139336583, 2.59997288006899, 3.7032320868021, 
5.40642614609066, 7.23884019003137, 5.30743533293025, 9.10524755249705, 
7.5565554674022, 6.89258777489288, 6.65674106952376, 7.09801583390161, 
7.02491962705643, 5.87441415384407, 2.22566924966015, 0.539426182393964, 
5.16883242134497, 8.80263246750633, 15.133649266248, 20.9065093335231, 
24.804849931059, 27.22404205069, 30.0112830892839, 33.7105842238466, 
33.148299672093, 28.9566605146087, 23.7557141914921, 14.8418199201637, 
8.03722695037173, 6.25444447810442, 21.8121838742914, 26.6222413990827, 
25.9680743217436, 26.8106000806074, 26.3415568350102, 25.0031712782548, 
22.9096265004055, 21.1041419714525, 3.72000091641834, 8.05063054052596, 
13.9794816114201, 24.904641775123, 34.023028503998, 40.7916930393454, 
44.2950843181925, 48.0110797482155, 50.9533674170092, 51.9781701747674, 
48.6404957370374, 40.4096134991892, 31.0983021543994, 21.692028504472, 
15.9728661585324, 12.8755052184241, 30.7772281295453, 35.8791796190767, 
33.8729890245313, 31.7538840828441, 31.0234864087387, 29.8625890835194
), hour = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3), weekday = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", 
"Sun"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), .Names = c("ABStemp", 
"hour", "weekday"), row.names = 2600:3100, class = "data.frame")
```

The above data frame contains the outlier value which is affecting my zlim() value. If you plot this data frame using my code you get the following result, which is fine.

[ABSerror http://danielcoakley.com/project/Testing/TemperatureIssue.png](http://danielcoakley.com/project/Testing/TemperatureIssue.png)

However, when plotting the entire data set, this one high value is distorting the visualisation. Is there any way of dealing with this without statistically removing the outliers?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to define the breaks using `boxplot.stats()`, outliers being outside the range of `boxplot.stats(ABStemp)$stats`. (FYI outliers are contained in `boxplot.stats(ABStemp)$out`).
One aesthetic downside is that you're loosing the continuous aspect of the color scheme.

```
breaks <- c(boxplot.stats(df$ABStemp)$stats,max(df$ABStemp,na.rm=TRUE)) 
#if you had some low outliers, you would use instead: c(min(ABStemp,na.rm=TRUE),boxplot.stats(ABStemp)$stats,max(ABStemp,na.rm=TRUE))
plot<-contourplot(ABStemp ~ hour * weekday,
                   aspect=0.3,
                   data = df,
                   #cuts = 200,
                   #labels=TRUE,
                   contour=FALSE,
                   region = TRUE,
                   #pretty=FALSE,
                   xlab = "Hour of Day",
                   ylab = "Day of Week",
                   col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("blue","yellow","red")),
                   at=breaks) #<-This is where you define your breaks for z
```

[image]

If the `boxplot.stats()` definition of an outlier doesn't suit your need you can modify that using `quantile()` instead of `boxplot.stats()` with you desired breakout points.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a workaround, based on your response @piannapus. I used the same 'at' function, but instead of using `boxplot.stats()`, I recaluated the statistics for my plotted data range, found the maximum and minimum values, and applied the `seq` function to find the cut points. This allowed me to maintain the smooth transition in the legend.

```
df<-df[!(is.na(df$ABStemp) | df$ABStemp==""), ] # Remove any NA/Blank values, where present
df1<-with(df, tapply(ABStemp, list(hour, month), mean))
max<-max(df1,na.rm=T)
min<-min(df1,na.rm=T)
seq <- seq(min,max,max/200)

plot2<-contourplot(ABStemp ~ hour * weekday,
                   aspect=0.3,
                   data = df,
                   #cuts = 200,
                   #labels=TRUE,
                   contour=FALSE,
                   region = TRUE,
                   pretty=FALSE,
                   at=seq,
                   xlab = "Hour of Day",
                   ylab = "Day of Week",
                   col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("blue","yellow","red")),
)
```

It might not be the most efficient way of solving the issue, but it works. Also, while making this change, I noted that contourplot was not even giving me the visual summary I required. I assumed it was automatically calculating the mean for each hour of day over each day of the year. Instead, however, it seems to have been using direct values from the original data frame, without computing a mean (i.e. only using values for a single instance, as opposed to summarising the data range). Anyway, below is the result of using the `tapply` function to do the computation.

[ABSerror http://danielcoakley.com/project/Testing/TemperatureIssueResolved.png](http://danielcoakley.com/project/Testing/TemperatureIssueResolved.png)